# Typescript type casting in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got the following interface.

```
export interface Student {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Besides that there is a component that holds an array of the type Student.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-students',
  templateUrl: './students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./students.component.css']
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {

  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'status'];
  students: Student[] = [];

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }

    this.studentService.addStudent({ name } as Student)
      .subscribe(student => {
        this.students.push(student);
      });
  }

}
```

In de studentService addStudent is defined as.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {

  private studentsUrl = 'api/students';  // URL to web api
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addStudent(student: Student): Observable<Student> {
    return this.http.post<Student>(this.studentsUrl, student, this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

When I would like to add a field to the interface like.

```
export interface Student {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    status: string;
}
```

How would I need to change the add function in the component? What I tried is the following.

```
add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }

    let newStudent = {
      'name': name,
      'status': 'testStatus'
    }

    this.studentService.addStudent({ newStudent } as Student)
      .subscribe(student => {
        this.students.push(student);
      });
  }
```

However this throws a warning in visual studio code.

```
Conversion of type '{ newStudent: { name: string; status: string; }; }' to type 'Student' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ newStudent: { name: string; status: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Student': id, name, statusts(2352)
```

Comment: what exactly fails? could you provide the code that you've tried and it didn't work?

Comment: @Andrei did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that there are plenty of opinions for a question like this so,
***I believe*** that the problem is on the `addStudent` function inside the service.
You say that your parameter is type of `Student`, but in reality you ask for a [Partial< Student >](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

```
addStudent(student: Partial<Student>): Observable<Student> {
    return this.http.post<Student>(this.studentsUrl, student, this.httpOptions);
}
```